# tidy nest() unexpected output

Tags: r, tidyr

In collapsing rows into a list with nest(), the output is not what I would expect. The result is a list like this:

> list(X1 = c("..."))

I would have expected:

> c("...")

An example using the [CNN dataset](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BwmD_VLjROrfTHk4NFg2SndKcjQ)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)

test <-    read_tsv("cnn/stories/0a0a4c90d59df9e36ffec4ba306b4f20f3ba4acb.story", 
             col_names = FALSE)

test2 <- test %>%
  nest(X1, .key = articles)
```

EDIT: So, if I wanted a solution that gives me the output of

> c("...")

I would have to do :

```
test3 <- test %>% 
  do(X1 = unique(unlist(.$X1)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation page for `tidyr::nest` (emphasis mine):

> `nest()` creates a **list** of data frames containing all the nested variables: this seems to be the most useful form in practice.

Comment: Yes, I have read the description. Your emphasis is making me realize that this is not the solution I am looking for.